# Eliminar espacio entre las filas y los registros

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando con un data frame y me gustaría saber como realizar un simple cambio estético (no sé como googlear exactamente la respuesta)

¿cómo elimino el espacio que está entre el nombre de los campos y los registros? Lo resalté en amarillo en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La totalidad del código está acá: [hardcoding_solution](https://github.com/jchemile/varios/blob/master/challenge/hardcoding_solution.ipynb)

Pero el data frame lo creo como es usual:

```
df = pd.read_csv('cellphoneslisting.csv', sep='',index_col='id')
```

En la documentación [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) encontré algunos métodos como header pero sin éxito.

Comment: Tu error tiene que ver con el indice, trata de aplicar .reset_index()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no me equivoco son varias formas las que hay pero te diré las que yo conozco:

1.- Para eliminar los espacios en blanco en todas partes:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
```

2.- Para eliminar espacios en blanco al principio de la cadena :

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lstrip()
```

3.- Para eliminar el espacio en blanco al final de la cadena :

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip()
```

4.- Para eliminar espacios en blanco en ambos extremos :

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```